# ggplot second line on y axis title not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot seem to get a second line no matter how I try to work it with the "\n" operator. I want some text, "TEST" to be on the second line. Any ideas how to make this work?

```
ytitle <- expression(bold(paste("Chlorophyll", italic(" a "), "(",mu, gL^-1,")", "\n TEST")))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + labs(y=ytitle)
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly add a sample data so we can reproduce your results

Comment: `ytitle <- list(bquote(bold(paste("Chlorophyll", italic(" a "), "(",mu, gL^-1,")"))), bquote("TEST"))` And if you replace `bquote` with `expression`, should still work.

Comment: Why not just use `labs(y=paste("Chlorophyll", ....." "\nTEST"))`. Note that I removed most of the actual text in there just to keep it simple as a comment, until I can formulate it into a proper answer once you formed a proper question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try `ylab(expression(atop(paste("Chlorophyll", italic(" a "), "(",mu, gL^-1,")"), "TEST")))`

Comment: @anotherFishGuy your answer is the only one that I could get to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use atop()

```
atop("above", "below")
```

[simple atop example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uivnS.png)

Change your ytitle to this.

```
ytitle <- expression(bold(atop(paste("Chlorophyll", italic(" a "), "(",mu, gL^-1,")"), "\n TEST")))
```

[Your y-axis label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CffEI.png)

Comment: Thank you, this works well! I tried atop but must have had something wrong in it!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here, thanks!

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + labs(y=expression(atop(paste("Chlorophyll", italic(" a "), "(",mu, gL^-1,")"), "TEST")))
```

[image]